# MASM Assembly '$' and '-'

Tags: assembly, command, masm

```
.data
    myarray BYTE "Hi there",0
    myarray_len EQU $-myarray
    myarray2 BYTE myarray_len DUP(' '); sets myarray_len number of
                                      ; bytes to be equal to ' '
```

I am trying to figure out what the second line in the above code does

```
myarray_len EQU $-myarray
```

I know its creating an item called `myarray_len` and that `EQU` will set the left side of that statement to the the right side similar to a #define in C++.  I am not sure what the `$-myarray` does.  Based on the rest of the code I could probably guess but that wouldn't help me a ton since I still wouldn't know what both symbols are doing.  I looked on this site and on several places on google and wikipedia, I know its a dumb simple question but I just couldn't find the answer.  I assume that the `$` has something to do with creating space in memory since its also used in `str$` but not sure what '-' does.

Answer (score 3):

`$` stands for the current address as the assembler is allocating space in the data segment. So, in this case it's subtracting the address at the end of `myarray` from the address at the beginning of `myarray`, to give the length of `myarray`.

Then `myarray2` is allocating the same amount of memory, but filling it with space characters.